# Background That Is Continuously Scrolling Downwards in Python With Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm very new to python and I have been trying to make a game. But I want to make the background continuously going down in a loop and I can't do it.
Here's my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

ship_width = 35
ship_height = 64

disp = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Jump")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg1 = pygame.image.load("Space.png")
bg2 = pygame.image.load("Space.png")

shipImg = pygame.image.load("Ship.png")

def ship(x,y):
    disp.blit(shipImg, (x,y))

def gameLoop():
    x = (width * 0.45)
    y = (height * 0.8)

x_ch = 0
y_ch = 0

x_bg = 0
y_bg = bg1.get_height()

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_ch = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_ch = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_ch = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_ch = 5


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_ch = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_ch = 0

    x += x_ch
    y += y_ch

    if x > width - ship_width or x < 0:
        x_ch = 0

    if y > height - ship_height or y < 0:
        y_ch = 0

    disp.blit(bg1, (0,x_bg))
    disp.blit(bg2, (0,y_bg))

    ship(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()

    x_bg += 1
    y_bg += 1

    if x_bg == -1 * x_bg.get_height(): #This is the part I'm stuck on
        x_bg = y_bg + y_bg.get_height() #When I run this i get and error:
                                       #if x_bg == -1 * x_bg.get_height():
                                        #AttributeError: 'int' object has no 
                                       #attribute 'get_height'
    if y_bg == -1 * y_bg.get_height():
        y_bg = x_bg + x_bg.get_height()

    clock.tick(30)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

So I get an error when i run this code but when I just write the background code on a new file it works but the background ends at some point it doesn't loop.
I've been trying to do this looping background for the past 3 days please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working thanks to mad meesh but the background ends at some point can someone tell me how i can loop it so it doesn't end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i've not used pygame before but just a quick glance at your code and the docs, it looks like you're calling `get_height()` on a number (`x_bg` and `y_bg`) not, what pygame refers to as a `surface` object.

the error, roughly translated, is saying that numbers  do not have a method with the name `get_height()`.

your `surface` objects are defined as `bg1` and `bg2` so my guess would be that those would have the method.

just swap the variables out with the correct ones and the error should be gone.

Comment: It works now thanks but now how do i get it to loop? it ends at some point.

Comment: i'm sure there are many ways to do it but here's a _very_ condensed description of
how i've achieved parallaxing planes:

assuming (0,0) is bottom left and you want to scroll the BG bottom to top:

`- 3 copies of the image
- h = img height
- align the copies at the same x
- img1.y = centered
- img2.y = h
- img3.y = h * 3 * -1
- define two variables 'scroll_speed' and 'distance = 0'`

on each frame

`- for each img do img.y += scroll_speed
- do distance += scroll_speed
- if distance > h, swap y of img2 with img3, reset distance to  0`

Comment: sorry i already got it working like an hour ago thanks anyways

Comment: ok. glad you got it worked out. i can't get the answer formatted properly in the comments anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what some of your code is trying to do, but I can get you started.

You can see the error says:
 "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_height'"

This is telling you that x_bg is an integer, and not an object, so it cannot access any attribute named 'get_height'. I would recommend learning more about objects and functions in python, and how they work.

It seems like you are already using x_bg and y_bg as the position of your backround, so there is no need to try to use any function called get_height, you can replace it with:

```
if x_bg == -1 * x_bg:
    x_bg = y_bg + y_bg
```

Another problem with this piece of code is that is is checking when the value of x_bg is *exactly equal* to a number. While this can sometimes work, especially when you are only dealing with integers, its usually a good idea to check whether your variable is greater/less than a number. for example if your background is at y = 99, and you are checking for y==100, but the screen is moving 2 pixels each step, your condition will never be reached, while if you are checking for y > 100 it should always be caught. you might want something like:

```
if y_bg < 0:
    y_bg = height
```

This won't work perfectly, but it shouldn't cause any errors and should help you get on the right track